# Should I use "achieve" or "achieving"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I would really appreciate some help with the following sentence if it's used as a headline.

> 10 steps to achieve your goals
>   10 steps to achieving your goals

I searched online and people are using both of them but I would like to understand the difference between them and when should I use each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in *10 steps to achieve your goals*, you don't need to do anything else but take *these ten steps* to achieve your particular goal.

In *10 steps to achieving your goals*, the ten steps may be not enough, but having made them, you  may get closer to achieving your goal, and you may need to take some more steps to achieve it.